# What Ubuntu version or flavor should I use?

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, amd-graphics, tor

My objective is to have a Linux PC just to run TOR browser. My laptop has an Intel Centrino Processor 1.70GHz with 512MB RAM, ATi Mobility Radeon 9600 128Mb. Which flavour do you suggest?

I have already tried:

- Lubuntu - freezes image on install
- Xubuntu - says processor is non-PAE
- Linux Mint - other problems and errors
- Puppy - other problems and errors

Also, every time I try to boot from USB, I get a boot error.

Comment: What are you asking here? More detail and structure please

Comment: It would be a lot more helpful if you narrowed down your distribution, and then posted the errors you have. Simply saying that you've had many errors over many distributions without much detail isn't helpful.

Comment: See also [How can I install on a non-PAE CPU? (error “Kernel requires features not present on the CPU: PAE”)](/q/117744/175814) for your secondary question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to go with the Lubuntu-16-04-LTS 32-bit image found here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Alternate_ISO - for your system this installer should do the charm.
On this [site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall) they say that it might take up to 90min for the installation to complete and that it does not hang even though there is nothing happening for a while.
If you get an error about pae-kernel you might have to add `forcepae` to the boot options as explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Changing_the_CD.27s_Default_Boot_Options).

As it appears, for your hardware these boot options `nomodeset` and `forcepae` need to be set in Grub.

So after installation is completed, I suggest you go get the [tor-browser-bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) from torproject.org.

Before you install it let's move it from Downloads to your home-directory; in a terminal type `mv ~/Downloads/tor-browser-linux32-6.0.5_LANG.tar.xz tor-browser-linux32-6.0.5_LANG.tar.xz`(replace LANG with appropiate language).

Now let's unpack it with `tar -xvJf tor-browser-linux32-6.0.5_LANG.tar.xz` then we switch into the newly created directory `cd tor-browser_LANG` and complete installation with `./start-tor-browser.desktop`.

Since we want the Tor-Browser be offered in the menu and not always click through directories, I suggest you run - still in the same terminal as above - `cp start-tor-browser.desktop ../.local/share/applications/start-tor-browser.desktop`

Good Night and Good Luck ;)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entirety of the conversation taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47958/discussion-on-answer-by-db429-what-ubuntu-version-or-flavor-should-i-use).  If you wish to continue, please go there.

Comment: thanks @ThomasWard. i tried move to chat but i wasnt able.

Comment: @JoãoBarros Next time, flag for moderator attention - we can always move comments to chat.